Предложение с разными видами связи (2)
Считается ли СПП с однородным соподчинением предложением с разными видами связи - подчинительной и сочинительной.

Я знаю, что завтра пойдет дождь и температура воздуха повысится.


Характеристика предложения:
  Многочленное сложноподчиненное предложение  с сочинительной связью однородных придаточных.

Смущает, что придаточные однородные.

Я знаю, что завтра пойдет дождь и (что) температура воздуха повысится.

Это СПП с двумя однородными изъяснительными придаточными предложениями, связанными сочинительной связью (союз И).  В сложном предложении три предикативные основы.

Основной будет ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ связь.  Главная часть СПП относится к обоим придаточным, а между собой они связаны сочинительным союзом И. Союз ЧТО во втором придаточном пропущен.

Разные виды связи  в предложениях другой структуры, например:

Он сказал, что подумает о моем предложении, и мы разошлись.
Это сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связь.

ТО есть не считается, если кратко?

Да, не считается.  Связь между придаточными может быть, к примеру, бессоюзной. Это вспомогательная связь, не основная.

Понятно. Спасибо.
